# Usb transfer crash

Tags: usb, freeze, crash, transfer

I have been researching for days and I do not know what to do.

When I am transferring data (30+ gb) from hard drive (ssd) to usb it will cause the computer to freeze and the only way to get out is to hold the power button.

I changed my dirty ratios to 0, as answered in another post but not working.

It makes life difficult to back up :(
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS